# Can't import rospy

Tags: ros, python, rospy, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a ROS aplication in Python and Qt, and when I run it from the terminal all is ok, but I try to run with double click (the script with the permissions and Nautilus configuration appropriate) and the aplication can't import rospy.

I use ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04.

Any idea? thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242096/can%27t-import-rospy/) by [akb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23480/akb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-08-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-21**:
`rospy` is not on the default `PYTHONPATH`, and so without sourcing the appropriate `/opt/ros/$distro/setup.*` script won't be resolvable for Python. It's probable that by 'double clicking', the environment is not properly setup, leading to the problems you describe.

**Comment by [akb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23480/akb/) on 2016-08-21**:
That happened, I could discovered it with you advice, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As gvdhoorn sais, the environment wasn't setup.

This link help me: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170156/bash-scripts-ran-from-from-gnome-nautilus-dont-have-enviroment-variables

I have put the ros variable enviroment in a new file ~/.myenvironmentvariables and I load it from ~/.bashrc (for Terminal) and from the file /etc/X11/Xsession.d/40x11-common_xsessionrc from Files Browser. Just with the code *source ~/.myenvironmentvariables*. And finally rospy can be import with double click in nautilus.

---

Originally posted by [akb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23480/akb/) with karma: 16 on 2016-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0